# How to moq responses from Amazon MWS for unit testing

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing, moq, amazon-mws

**Context**

I'm unit testing a C# .Net class that calls the `ListMatchingProducts` operation in the Amazon MWS API (using MWSClientCsRuntime).

**Issue**

The Amazon MWS API is a moving target with product data changing all the time so I'd like to be able to moq the `ListMatchingProductsResponse` object that the API returns.  I can fetch API responses using the MWS scratchpad and store these in xml files. But then, in unit tests, I need to coerce data from these files into a `ListMatchingProductsResponse` object.

**Question**

How can I load this xml data into a `ListMatchingProductsResponse` object? (I notice that the object has a `ReadFragmentsFrom` method but I can't see how this might be used).

**Code**

```
[TestClass]
public class PossibleAmazonProductMatchesTests
{
    string testDataDirectory = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + @"\Test data";

    [TestMethod]
    public void FindSpanners()
    {
        // Arrange

        ListMatchingProductsRequest request = new ListMatchingProductsRequest("secret key", "market id", "spanner");
        ListMatchingProductsResult result = new ListMatchingProductsResult();

        ListMatchingProductsResponse response = new ListMatchingProductsResponse();

        string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(this.testDataDirectory + @"\Spanners Response.xml");

        // *** The issue - How do I coerce xmlString into response? ***

        var client = new Mock<MarketplaceWebServiceProductsClient>();
        client.Setup(c => c.ListMatchingProducts(request)).Returns(response);

        // Act

        // This is the method being tested. It calls ListMatchingProducts which is being mocked.
        PossibleAmazonProductMatches possibleAmazonProductMatches = new PossibleAmazonProductMatches("spanners", client);

        // Assert

        Assert.IsTrue(possibleAmazonProductMatches.SpannersFound == true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] (code) that demonstrates the scenario and better explains your issue.

Comment: @Nkosi All done.

Comment: This looks like a simple case of having to read the XML file deserializing it from XML to the desired object type. Just want to make sure I understand what you want done.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense.  Best therefore that I abandon my current strategy of using the MWS scratchpad to obtain xml and pasting this into a file.  Better to code something that reads from the API and serialises this into a file.  I can then deserialize this when testing.

Happy to mark this as the answer if you'd care to post something below.

Comment: The MarketplaceWebServiceProductsSample.cs file included in the client library is the starting point.  Fill in your details, uncomment your code and follow through in the debugger.  You will see how It deserializes into the appropriate object for you.  You could do it manually of course, but just look at the code, it's all there.

Comment: @ScottG Many thanks for this. Delving around in the client library I see that MarketplaceWebServiceProductsMock.cs gives me a fully worked example.  Coupled with the remarks from Nkosi it looks like I can get a useful abstraction going here.  I'll post some working code once I have it.

Comment: Great to hear, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a simple case of having to read the XML file and then deserializing it from XML to the desired object type.

Better yet you can abstract that behind a service that performs your desired behavior without tightly coupling the code to implementation concerns.

Treat the the MWS as a 3rd part service and wrap that behind an abstraction you have total control over. That way you can configure the desired behavior when testing.

Comment: Thanks.  Will update my code example once I've tidied things up.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the great responses from @Nkosi and @ScottG I now have a working solution which turns out to be unspeakably simple, albeit with a few important points to note.  So the unit test code goes:

```
[TestClass]
public class PossibleAmazonProductMatchesTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // Arrange

        var moqClient = new MarketplaceWebServiceProductsMock();

        // Act

        PossibleAmazonProductMatches possibleAmazonProductMatches = new PossibleAmazonProductMatches("spanners", moqClient);

        // Assert

        Assert.IsTrue(possibleAmazonProductMatches.PossibleProductList.Count == 10);
    }
}
```

..and that's it.  Could it get any simpler!

For abstraction the object under test (PossibleAmazonProductMatches) has this constructor:

```
public PossibleAmazonProductMatches(string searchTerm, MarketplaceWebServiceProducts.MarketplaceWebServiceProducts client)
{
    // Some processing
}
```

The important points to note are:

- MarketplaceWebServiceProducts is actually an *interface* despite the fact that it doesn't follow the ISomething naming convention.
- MarketplaceWebServiceProducts is also used as a *namespace name* hence the need for the doubled up MarketplaceWebServiceProducts.MarketplaceWebServiceProducts syntax in the PossibleAmazonProductMatches constructor.
- MarketplaceWebServiceProductsMock is included in the MWS package so there's nothing to code.
- By default MarketplaceWebServiceProductsMock reads from a fixed xml template file buried in the assembly and uses this to build your test response.  You edit this file as required.  I actually want to create my own xml files sourced from the MWS scratchpad and want to store these in a more convenient location.  I thought I could inherit from MarketplaceWebServiceProductsMock and override the relevant code to do this but this turns out to be buried in a private method.  I've therefore simply copied the MarketplaceWebServiceProductsMock and altered it to meet my needs. Hence my mock now looks like this:

  ```
  using MarketplaceWebServiceProducts.Model;
  using System;
  using System.IO;
  using MWSClientCsRuntime;

  namespace AmazonMWS.Tests
  {
  public class MyMWSMock : MarketplaceWebServiceProducts.MarketplaceWebServiceProducts
  {

      // Definitions of most methods removed for brevity. They all match the pattern of ListMatchingProductsResponse.

      public ListMatchingProductsResponse ListMatchingProducts(ListMatchingProductsRequest request)
      {
          return newResponse<ListMatchingProductsResponse>();
      }

      private T newResponse<T>() where T : IMWSResponse
      {
          FileStream xmlIn = File.Open("D:\\MyTestDataFolder\\Test1.xml", FileMode.Open);
          try
          {
              StreamReader xmlInReader = new StreamReader(xmlIn);
              string xmlStr = xmlInReader.ReadToEnd();

              MwsXmlReader reader = new MwsXmlReader(xmlStr);
              T obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
              obj.ReadFragmentFrom(reader);
              obj.ResponseHeaderMetadata = new ResponseHeaderMetadata("mockRequestId", "A,B,C", "mockTimestamp", 0d, 0d, new DateTime());
              return obj;
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              throw MwsUtil.Wrap(e);
          }
          finally
          {
              if (xmlIn != null) { xmlIn.Close(); }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

The [C# client library](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/cSharp.html/135-9205645-9734230) has been around for several years and works right out of the box.  You don't have to deal with any XML, the deserializing is included.  If you don't want to use their code but want to see how it's done, open it up into Visual Studio and copy out the parts you want.  I have used all of the C# libraries and they're pretty good.  You find what operation you want and uncomment their code and run.  I believe they have sample XML data with all the responses that you'll get from the various operations.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I've also used these libraries successfully and have a couple of projects live.  The issue here is that I'm trying to create unit tests that simulate API responses so that results are predictable. Hence I'm trying to fetch a real API response, store it and reuse it again in tests.  I fetch and store to an xml file using MWS scratchpad and an editor.  I can't figure out how to coerce file contents into a ListMatchProductsResponse object however.